# AspnetBoilerplate LazyLoading not working

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I'm having some problem with LazyLoading on the response of the AsyncCrudAppService Create method. After the objects creation, it returns the respective EntityDto but the classes inside aren't loaded.

Ex:[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02ZO7.png)

Notice that the feature object "loaded" because I used the GetAllIncluding method, but the Project or the list of Scenarios are null. It stopped work out of nowhere.

Comment: "...It stopped work out of nowhere..." - this information is not really helpful. It does not say what exactly did not work, i.e. did you get any error messages anywhere, did you try to debug the issue to make sure that it actually does the intended thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that would be because EF Core does not (yet) support lazy loading.

[Entity Framework - lazy loading or additional async/await query method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45421267/entity-framework-lazy-loading-or-additional-async-await-query-method)